# Build-Max-Heap vs. HeapSort

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, heaps, heap-sort

I'm not sure whether my definition for these 2 terms are correct. Hence, could you help me verify that:

**HeapSort:** A procedure which sorts an array in place.

**Build-Max-Heap:** A procedure which runs in linear time, produces a max- heap from an unordered input array.

Is worst-case input = worst-case running time?

If so, given the size *n* for Build-Max-Heap, would its worst case input be the same as the HeapSort which is $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$?

Comment: Famously, building a heap is possible in linear time.

Answer (score 4):

> HeapSort: A procedure which sorts an array in place.

Can be in-place or not in-place, the point is it's using a heap data structure to help sort.

Building heap is linear with a careful analysis

See more [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/351/mount/lectures/lect14-heapsort-analysis-part.pdf)